# RavenDB Index: Need a solution to merge 2 dictionary fields into a single dictionary, flatten it and make it searchable

Tags: c#, ravendb

We are building a nested UI view for a customer and require a solution to merge 2 dictionary fields into a single consolidated dictionary as well as make the keys searchable as though they are field names. I managed to create a Map/Reduce index using the techniques mentioned in http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/advanced/dynamic-fields and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ravendb/c0HdJT-yyvQ/qvkVRrZfvmgJ.

```
public class ViewFolderResultWithIndividualProperties
        {
            public string EntryId { get; set; }
            public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> MetadataProperties { get; set; }            
            public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> NamedProperties { get; set; }
            public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Properties { get; set; }
            public string FlattenedProperties { get; set; }
            public string _ { get; set; }       
        }
```

MetadateProperties – it is a dictionary of Key, Value pairs. For e.g.,

```
"MetadataProperties": [
    {
      "Key": "JobName",
      "Value": "one job"
    },
    {
     "Key": "Organization",
      "Value": "foo"
    }]
```

NamesProperties – it is a dictionary of known Key, Value pairs. For e.g.,

```
"NamedProperties": [
    {
      "Key": "Tags",
      "Value": ""
    },
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "file-184"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Uploader",
      "Value": "rmani@transper.com"
    },
    {
      "Key": "FileType",
      "Value": "Jpg"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Language",
      "Value": "English"
    }]
```

Properties –  It is a merged Dictionary that contains the Key, Value pairs from both MetadataProperties and NamedProperties.

FlattenedProperties and _ are the properties that contains the flattened field values of “NamedProperties” and “MetadataProperties” respectively. I can’t figure out a way to flatten a computed Property like “Properties” (which combines both MetadataProperties and NamedProperties dictionaries). I tried Concat

Here’s the Index creation code:

```
public class PortalEntryViews_DocumentIdSplitIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<PortalEntry, ViewFolderResultWithIndividualProperties>
        {
            public PortalEntryViews_DocumentIdSplitIndex()
            {
                Map = portalEntries => from portalEntry in portalEntries
                                       select new 
                                                     {
                                                         EntryId = portalEntry.Id,
                                                         MetadataProperties = portalEntry.MetaData.Select(t => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(t.Key, t.Value)).ToList(),                                                         
                                                         NamedProperties = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { 
                                                             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Tags", string.Join(",", portalEntry.Tags.Where(t => !t.IsInternal).Select(t=>t.Name))),
                                                             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", portalEntry.Name),
                                                             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Uploader", portalEntry.Uploader),
                                                             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("FileType", portalEntry.FileType),
                                                             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Language", portalEntry.Language),
                                                             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", portalEntry.Name) },
                                                             Properties = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(),
                                                             FlattenedProperties = "",
                                                         _ = ""                                                         
                                                     };


                Reduce = results => from result in results                                    
                                    group result by new { result.EntryId, result.MetadataProperties, result.NamedProperties, result.FlattenedProperties, result._ } into g
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        EntryId = g.Key.EntryId,
                                        MetadataProperties = g.Key.MetadataProperties,
                                        NamedProperties = g.Key.NamedProperties,
                                        Properties = g.Key.MetadataProperties.Concat(g.Key.NamedProperties).ToList(),
                                        FlattenedProperties = g.Key.NamedProperties.Select(f => CreateField(f.Key, f.Value)),
                                        _ = g.Key.MetadataProperties.Select(t => CreateField(t.Key, t.Value, true, true))
                                    };


            }
        }
```

When I run a query like “Language:English” from RavenDb Explorer directly, it works and returns a projection. Whereas when I run the same query using LuceneQuery from within my C# code:

```
var entries =
                    session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<ViewFolderResultWithIndividualProperties>(
                        "PortalEntryViews/DocumentIdSplitIndex")
                        .WhereEquals("Language", "English").ToList();
```

I get this error:

```
Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Could not read value for property: FlattenedProperties  ----> Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray
```

My ultimate goal is to flatten the combined dictionary i.e. Properties field into a single field using CreateField() that can be searched using the keys as though they are field names. But, if I use a call like this:

`Properties = g.Key.MetadataProperties.Concat(g.Key.NamedProperties).ToList().Select(t => CreateField(t.Key, t.Value, true, true))`,  it seems to run but when you look at the index from Ravendb  Explorer, it shows the actual error:

Stage: Indexing Section:Reduce Description: ‘System.Collections.Generic.List’ does not contain definition for ‘Select’

Right now, I’m only able to flatten only one Dictionary (MetadataProperties) into that “_” field in reduce section, which works from both Ravendb Explorer and from C# code using LuceneQuery but that does not meet my requirement.

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search key-value only, you can do it very simple

```
//the index
public class FlattenIndex: AbstractIndexCreationTask<PortalEntry>
    {
        public class ReduceResult
        {
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
        public FlattenIndex()
        {
            Map = portalEntries => from portalEntry in portalEntries                                                               
                                   from p in portalEntry.MetadataProperties.Concat(portalEntry.NamedProperties)
                           select new
                           {
                               Key=p.Key,
                               Value=p.Value
                           };
        }
    }

//the query
 using (var session = _docStore.OpenSession())
            {
                var someEntries = session.Query<FlattenIndex.ReduceResult, FlattenIndex>()
                    .Where(x => x.Key == "Language" && x.Value == "English")
                    .As<PortalEntry>()
                    .ToArray();
                if (someEntries!=null)
                    foreach(var entry in someEntries )
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(entry.Id);
                    }
            }
```